# Blocking pop-up adverts in YouTube videos

Tags: firefox, website, youtube, advertisements

I don't have a problem with unobtrusive adverts and why shouldn't websites try to make money from it's users? (someone's gotta pay for the servers!)

But what I really find annoying are the adverts popping up in YouTube video's which I find distracting as hell.

[image]

My question is this, how do I block those sorts of ad's without blocking non-obtrusive everyday adverts?

I'm on a Mac (Leopard) using Firefox.

Comment: Since this is relevant to anyone using Firefox, I'm removing the [tag:osx] tag

Comment: So _these_ ads were annoying back then... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy as Pie!  Download the addon for fire fox called "Adblock plus"

After installed goto youtube and click on a video, while it is playing click on the ABP icon in the top right corner of your screen.

Click on anything that says "google" in it.

Click the bubble next to the one that eliminates anything from google "http://www.google.com/*"or something similar

Click add filter on the bottom right of your Adblock screen

POOF!  No more ad pop ups!

:)

Answer (score 3):

You'll be able to block video ads before a video if you add also those record in your **hosts** file:

> 127.0.0.1 s0.2mdn.net
>
> 127.0.0.1 s1.2mdn.net

Complete and better explained procedure here: http://www.lolloland.com/2012/12/12/technote-how-to-remove-video-ads-youtube/

Cheers! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just install [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/1865)? Though that would not allow for your *why shouldn't websites try to make money from it's users*...

EDIT: I now see I actually missed your real question, *how do I block those sorts of ad's **without blocking non-obtrusive everyday adverts**?* One could use Adblock to *only* block Google advertisements, but I guess many sites actually use Google ads, so that would still block too much for your liking. I'll leave my answer here for a while, to avoid others reading as bad as I did.

EDIT 2: One could enable Adblock on YouTube only (or *maybe* for `s.ytimg.com`, which seems to be the static [non-cookie](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/03/01/performance-research-part-3/) video server), but like joshhunt [wrote](https://superuser.com/questions/23374/blocking-pop-up-adverts-in-youtube-videos/23378#23378), YouTube needs the money as well...

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't dare to mark my **wrong** answer a community wiki, as I doubted if I could still delete it then. And now it has been accepted. Funny world. ;-) Let's wait some more time to see if other answers are posted...

Answer (score 2):

In-video ads and annotations can be hidden by using [YouTube Auto Buffer & Auto HD & Remove Ads for Greasemonkey](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/49366).

Have a look at my [screenshot](https://superuser.com/questions/487361/how-can-i-stop-youtube-videos-from-auto-playing/488314#488314), usage is self-explaining, just ensure the tickmarks for 'hide in-video ads' and 'annotations' are set. Other advertisements on the website are still left there.

Answer (score 1):

However annoying they are, you cannot turn the ad overlays off. See [my answer](https://superuser.com/questions/17460/avg-popup-upgrade-ad/17462#17462) to a [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/17460/avg-popup-upgrade-ad):

> **No.**

Advertising is how these websites make their money and, [by the sounds of it](http://www.contentinople.com/author.asp?section_id=450&doc_id=178092), Google needs every last ad that brings them money.

Comment: As much as I agree that sites should be able to make money, I also feel that they've got themselves to blame for using overlays and for using advertising agencies that go all the way to abuse one's privacy. Google surely being one of them. I actually started using Adblock to block Google Analytics, and the blocking of advertisements was a nice side effect for me...

Comment: I don't mind pre-roll ad's/ ad breaks but their is something about those pop-out ad's that really annoys.

Answer (score 1):

Adding:

```
127.0.0.1 m1.emea.2mdn.net.edgesuite.net
127.0.0.1 googleads.g.doubleclick.net
```

to `/etc/hosts` will disable the ads system-wide, but it might affect some other sites too.

**Update:** without adding `pagead2.googlesyndication.com`, I have found this to be unreliable. This addition does pose a threat to other sites.

Comment: have you tried this yourself?

Comment: Yes. On further investigation, it doesn't always work unless you add pagead2.googlesyndication.com, which will almost certainly affect other sites.

Answer (score 1):

In ABP: Filter preferences- Add filter  "||youtube.com/annotations_invideo?*"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately

> No

, outside of clicking on the "X" to close the advertisement, you will always see these ads on YouTube Partner videos...

The ads are what keeps YouTube free and it is compensation to the YouTube Partner's efforts for creating popular videos to incentive for them to continue to make popular videos...

Source(s):http://youtube-answers.blogspot.com

Comment: Hmmm, I've never seen those advertisements when using Adblock (for Safari in my case). Any example videos?

Comment: what about this video, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Thhyeop5gW8, can you see the pop-up ad their?

Comment: No, no adds for that movie. (I watched 4'30 minutes until disabling Adblock, which after reloading indeed gave me adds almost immediately. I have also blocked Flash from storing Local Shared Objects and other trails as per http://superuser.com/questions/1627/how-to-automatically-remove-flash-history-privacy-trail-or-stop-flash-from-storing-it but that doesn't have any effect on the YouTube advertisements.)

Comment: @nam3d: I can't. Using Firefox and AdBlock.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can't, as the ad system is embedded into the flash player Youtube is using.

I'm curious though about how any Firefox addin may block them, but it sounds like a false statement that they can/might. Adblock Plus has an option that lists all blockable items on a web page, and the ads embedded into the flash player isn't on that list.

When it comes to the "moral aspects" of blocking ads on a web page: It's up the user to decide what he or she is willing to see on his/her computer, and has nothing to do with the question asked here.

Comment: The advertisements are dynamic, so will need to contact the advertisement-server to get the ads that are personalized just for you. As such, blocking the ad-server (currently) surely disables showing any ads. Like I wrote in a comment above: I never knew YouTube was embedding ads until I did some testing today... Future versions of the player could refuse to play when the ad-server cannot be reached (but even then someone may just come up with a dummy server that does respond, but returns no advertisements).

Comment: @Arjan: OK, I saw your "edit 2" now, and I agree that blocking the ad-server itself seems to be a pretty reasonable solution.

Comment: By the way: for http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Thhyeop5gW8 disabling Adblock makes YouTube request additional data from ad.doubleclick.net, n4061ad.fr.doubleclick.net, pagead2.googlesyndication.com,  googleads.g.doubleclick.net and m1.emea.2mdn.net. With Adblock enabled I don't see the tiny yellow ad-marker below the player controls either.

Answer (score 0):

Grab both the [MVPS hosts file](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm), and the [hphosts file](http://www.hosts-file.net/?s=Download).

After you merge those hosts files together, disable the Windows DNS service (to avoid slowdown from having a 6.5 MB hosts file) and you'll be all good.

I no longer get a single ad on Youtube.